# How to setup OutputCahce only for Release configuration not Debug in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

Let's assume the following code:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60,VaryByCustom="Browser")]
public ActionResult CachableAction(string SomeParameter)
{
   return View();
}
```

I know that `Output caching lets you store the output of an action method in memory on the Web server. For example, if the action method renders a view, the view page will be cached.`

**I don't want to cache my pages in Debug configuration.**

What settings are need for to apply cache only in `Release` configuration **not** `Debug` ?

I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web.config.debug file is used only when you build a deployment package. If you run your site locally in Cassini for example it is completely ignored. So you may try disabling cache in your web.config:

```
<caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
</caching>
```

and in your web.config.release enable the cache. Note though that if you don't use the web deployment package feature those files are completely ignored.

Answer (score 3):

For attributes, you could just go for using preprocessor directive

```
#if !DEBUG
[OutputCache(Duration=60,VaryByCustom="Browser")]
#endif
public ActionResult CachableAction(string SomeParameter)
{
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this i am doing in my testing project 
in my controller i do like this in below

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "ParamA;ParamB;")]
        public PartialViewResult CachData(string someparameter)
        {
            string returnvalue = string.Format("parameter :{0} date : {1}", someparameter, DateTime.Now.ToString());
            return PartialView("CachData", returnvalue);
        }
```

and in my view

```
@model string 
<p>
    This is my cach Action</p>
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

i think this will help you...

Comment: And where is the setting for Release configuration ? I don't want to cache my pages in Debug mode.